# terraform azurerm_scheduled_query_rules_log

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

Hi I'm running terraform
Terraform v0.13.4

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.41.0

I'm trying to set up azure metric monitoring for vm

```
resource "azurerm_scheduled_query_rules_log" "scheduled_rules" {
  for_each = local.alert_rules
  name                = "${var.client_initial}-${each.key}"
  location            = var.resource_group_name.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  criteria {
    metric_name = each.value.metric_name
    dimension {
      name     = "Computer"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = var.virtual_machines
    }
  }
  data_source_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_ID
  description    = each.value.description
  enabled        = true
}
```

However when i run plan, it tells me

```
53: resource "azurerm_scheduled_query_rules_log" "scheduled_rules" {

The provider provider.azurerm does not support resource type
"azurerm_scheduled_query_rules_log".
```

I see this new resource is introduced in azurerm 2.1, not sure why it's not available on 2.41.0?

Comment: Do you have any questions in my reply?

Comment: Hi Nancy, thanks for your help! Once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also face the same error. It should be the resource `azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_log` instead of `azurerm_scheduled_query_rules_log`. There might be some mistakes or do not update in the terraform [Example Usage](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_scheduled_query_rules_log#example-usage).

[image]

Here is a working example with Terraform `v0.14.3` + azurerm `v2.41.0`

```
# Example: LogToMetric Action for the named Computer
resource "azurerm_monitor_scheduled_query_rules_log" "example" {
  name                = format("%s-queryrule", "some")
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  criteria {
    metric_name = "Average_% Idle Time"
    dimension {
      name     = "Computer"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["targetVM"]
    }
  }
  data_source_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  description    = "Scheduled query rule LogToMetric example"
  enabled        = true
}
```

[image]